# release COM port after killing process

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a C# application that uses D-Link GSM Modem to send/receive SMS messages.

Now for some reason the D-Link USB gets disconnected and reconnected automatically after some time (random). When it re-connects it opens up the D-Link Connection Manager which reserves the COM4.

Now when my application run and tries to send SMS it fails, because it doesn't find any available (already in use my D-Link Manager).

when i tried as at application load if the D-Link Process is there I'm killing it using process.kill(). That kills the application but still the COM4 remains inaccessible.

Is there a way to kill the process and release the COM port also programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing a process doesn't give it a chance to clean up. It is easy for COM ports to get hung up if clients terminate abnormally.

Try [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Hopefully, the process will respond by shutting down normally and closing the COM port. You would have to give it some time to shut down, though, for which you could use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `SerialPort` class implements `IDisposable` for exactly this reason: to clean up unmanaged resources (like the port itself) when the port variable goes out of scope.

```
using (var serialPort = new SerialPort())
{
    // Set the read/write timeouts
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

    serialPort.Open();

    // do something
}
```

It won't always get cleaned up when you kill the process, but this way, you're giving it a fighting chance.

Answer (score 0):

one should blame poorly designed operating system for not being capable to clean the resources of the process after killing it

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution to problem or answer the question in any way